# Replace a string if it's not a comment or inside quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, replace

I'm making a Javascript superset ( just as a hobby ), and i need to replace my superset's keywords with javascript ones, but when i use something like:

```
.replace(/set/g, "var")
```

it replaces every occurrence of "set", even inside strings or comments like:

```
from: // set this to that

to: // var this to that
```

So, how i can make it replace only if its outside comments or strings?

Comment: You might want to use something like jison to parse your superset instead of regex replaces. Regex isn't a good solution for this problem as there are so many scenarios where the word "set" may be used in other scenarios, e.g. in a string or a name

Comment: Any link to it?

Comment: That's the problem, it can be found even on comments and will be replaced.

Comment: https://github.com/zaach/jison

Comment: Ok, by taking a look on it, i discovered that it's not what i want

Comment: I want something to replace text if it's not inside quotes, or in a comment, and not making a fully fledged parser just for such a simple task.

Comment: Actually, if you want to do that right, it's exactly what you want. Compiler construction (that's what you are doing here) is a complex task ... It's more than just replacing a few characters here and there

Comment: There are other places where you wouldn't want to replace `set`, like in regex literals. Also template literals will be a challenge, as they alternate code with string literals.... you've just scratched the surface.

Answer (score -2):

That depends on how your "superset" is built. Since strings can contain all characters and spaces can come after the quotes it is hard to tell if the keyword is a keyword or just part of a string.
Normally you wouldn't just replace such keywords with regular expressions but scan the whole code of your superset and then you can do what you want with it.

I recommend this book by Bob Nystrom which is very beginner friendly.
https://craftinginterpreters.com/contents.html

Comment: Ok. but what i want is to just transpile some code into javascript by switching keywords

Comment: @IsaacVinícius Usually you would parse the code, create an abstract syntax tree and interpret it. Jison is an appropriate tool for this  That's not a task you would solve by a simple replace. You could read the source code of TypeScript or CoffeeScript. Both are open source transpilers.

Comment: @IsaacVinícius
Let's say we have the following pseudocode
`set myVar = " set your variable with keyword set "`
Then you want to replace only the first set but you have to tell in your regex when not to replace it or better create a condition because of which it should be replaced, otherwise all "set" words are the same and the scanner doesn't know why not to replace it. It would be different if you let your keywords start with i.e. a dollar sign, so `$set myVar ...`. This can also be in strings and comments and is unlikely, but possible. The better variant would still be to build a lexer.

Comment: I'll try, but sounds weird.